# Text before and after Router Links in new Line don't have spacing in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm having a strange behaviour and I would like to know if there is a workaround (not talking about `&nbsp;`.

I'm using react-router and using the `<Link>` Component.

The code I'm working with looks something like this:

```
    <p className="text-small">
      Schon einen Account? - Jetzt einfach hier 
      <Link to="/anmelden">anmelden</Link>!
    </p>
```

in the frontend the text gets redered as:

```
Schon einen Account? - Jetzt einfach hieranmelden!
                                        ^ no space
```

While, when using an `<a>` Tag

```
    <p className="text-small">
      Schon einen Account? - Jetzt einfach hier 
      <a href="/anmelden">anmelden</a>!
    </p>
```

The Text gets rendered as:

```
Schon einen Account? - Jetzt einfach hier anmelden!
                                         ^ space
```

Sure, I could use `&nbsp;` right after "hier" or write the paragraph as one line instead of a linebreak, but I'd like to keep the code as readable as possible and the content itself might come from a translation file in the future. Is there any way I could force react to display the `" "` when using a linebreak?